# Java static and thread safety or what to do

Tags: java, thread-safety

I am extending a library to do some work for me. Here is the code:

```
public static synchronized  String decompile(String source, int flags,UintMap properties,Map<String,String> namesMap)
    {
        Decompiler.namesMap=namesMap;
        String decompiled=decompile(source,flags,properties);
        Decompiler.namesMap=null;
        return decompiled;

    }
```

The problem is that `namesMap` is static variable. Is that thread safe or not? Because if this code runs concurently namesMap variable may change. What can I do for this?

Comment: Is namesMap accessed elsewhere in the code? If so, can you give a specific example?

Comment: it would be accessed from the other decompile() only..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *method* `decompile` is thread-safe (it will never be running on two threads concurrently), but if *anything* other than that method also uses the `namesMap`, then no, overall this is not thread-safe: Another method *other* than `decompile` running on a different thread could modify the map while the `decompile` method is using it, presumably causing mayhem. :-)

You might look at the classes in the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) namespace (for instance, [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)) to see if any of those are applicable to what you're doing.

**Edit** (Responding to your comment.) If the static member `namesMap` is *only ever used* by `decompile` and not by anything else (you don't get a reference to it to anything else, etc.), then you're fine. The fact it's a static doesn't matter, if the only place it's used is serialized.

Comment: And that "*only ever used*" means that one day, another developer will forget about this implicit requirement and use it elsewhere and you'll get spurious errors.

Comment: If the static member `namesMap` is only used in one place, why not just change it from a static member to a method parameter? This way you can remove all doubt.

Comment: @matt: He has to store it *somewhere*. :-) Java doesn't have C's behavior with static local variables. (I'm not saying it's a bad thing it doesn't, just that it doesn't.)

Comment: @T.J. What I meant was instead of storing the reference in a static var so that the other `decompile()` method can access it, it would make more sense to simply change the other `decompile()` method to accept this Map as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

If there is a chance that other threads will make changes to `namesMap` while the method `decompile(String, int, UintMap, Map)` as described above is running, then you should be making a copy of the map passed in rather than just assigning a reference.

```
Decompiler.namesMap= new HashMap<String, String>(namesMap);
```

If there is a chance that other threads will make changes *to the elements contained within the map, and not just the structure of the map itself*, then you should make sure that your `decompile()` method and the other threads using `namesMap` are guarded by the same lock.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Decompiler.namesMap=namesMap;` 
is the only place to set namesMap

But nowhere else in the code the namesMap is changed..
Only read...

I want to ensure that

```
String decompiled=decompile(source,flags,properties);
```

would use the same namesMap.

Answer (score 0):

There will only be one namesMap so you don't have to worry whether it would use the same namesMap. It would.